# How to add a list with recent changes on files of a Sharepoint 2013 site?

Tags: 2013, list

I would like to display a list of recent changes, which have been made on files of a specific Sharepoint site. So, the list should only show changes of files from this specific site, not changes of files, which are displayed on other sites of the Sharepoint.
Unfortunately my company does not allow adding the "recent changes" web part, which is why it is not a solution for me. I also found an answer here in StackExchange about changing the query button to "recently changed items" but unfortunately, my query button does not offer the possibility "recently changed items", which is why this is also not an option for me.
Thank you for your help!